# How to create a measure that calculates sum for the previous month in the Previous year?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to calculate the number of notices in the previous month in the previous year. For example,
we are now in January 2024, so, I am trying to Calculate the cases that Happened in **December 2022**

I created a measure as follows but it keeps giving me a Blank Value

Also, I have a Master Calendar ( MasterDate), and Column I am trying to Calculate is (KPI 10 [Days OVER 3) With a 1-1 Relationship

```
KPI 10 TB NO Days Over 3 Last Month Previous Year = 
var m = 
IF(MONTH(TODAY()) = 1,
    CALCULATE(SUM('KPI10'[DAYS OVER 3]), FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1), FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = YEAR(TODAY())-2)),
    CALCULATE(SUM('KPI10'[DAYS OVER 3]), FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1), FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = YEAR(TODAY())-1)))
return
m
```

It is giving me BLANK instead of Number

Answer (score 1):

Your filters look wrong to me.

```
CALCULATE(
     SUM('KPI10'[DAYS OVER 3])
     , FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1)
     , FILTER(MasterDate, MasterDate[Date] = YEAR(TODAY())-2)
)
```

First, MONTH() and YEAR() return integers, and I'm assuming the value in MasterDate[Date] is likely to be some kind of date data type -- so that doesn't work.

Next, you are calculating the sum of everything in KPI10[DAYS OVER 3] where two conditions are met:  When `MasterDate[Date]` = `Today's Month - 1`  AND when `MasterDate[Date]` = `Today's Year - 2` ... those two conditions aren't likely to ever both be true, right?  For the most part `Today's Month - 1` <> `Today's Year - 2`

---

Save yourself some trouble and do this differently.  First, recognize that 1 year and 1 month ago = 13 months ago.  Then do something like this:

```
KPI 10 TB NO Days Over 3 Last Month Previous Year = 

CALCULATE(
    SUM('KPI10'[DAYS OVER 3])
    , PARALLELPERIOD(MasterDate[Date],-13,month)
)
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but it didn't work for the following reason, When I applied your answer, it did shift the dataset 13 months ago, but it didn't sum only that month, but it did the aggregation from the beginning of the dataset to 13 months ago. So, your solution aggregated from the Start of my Dataset, which is Jan 2021 to the end of December 2022. which is not my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The work around this issue is to create a calculated column in the Master Calendar Table, which gives 1 if the date is in the Previous Month in the Last Year, and the rest is 0

So, basically it is a 0 or 1 Calculated Column, and I created it as follows:

```
IsLastonthPreviousYear = 
var currentdate=  MAX('MasterDate'[Date]) 
var LastMonthPreviousYearEndDate=DATE(YEAR(currentdate)-1, Month(currentdate),1)-1
var LastMonthPreviousYearStartDate= DATE(YEAR(LastMonthPreviousYearEndDate),
MONTH(LastMonthPreviousYearEndDate), 1)
return
IF('MasterDate'[Date]<=LastMonthPreviousYearEndDate &&
'MasterDate'[Date]>=LastMonthPreviousYearStartDate, 1, 0)
```